# Evento Blur não funciona em celular

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um evento **JavaScript** `Blur` que não funciona em celulares. Funciona perfeitamente em desktops. Inclusive em navegadores mais antigos.

Meu código:

**HTML**

```
<label>CPF</label>
<input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" />
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#cpf').blur(function () {
    var chars = (this.value);
    $.post(URL + 'Ajax/buscaCpf', {val: chars}, function (busca) {
        $('#resultado').html(busca);
    });
    });
```

**PHP/Ajax**

```
$char = $_POST['val'];

$cpf_key = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', null, $char);

$dados = connection::select("select * from tabela where cpf='".$char."'");
$reg = $dados - > fetchObject();

if (validador::validCPF($char)) {
    if (!empty($reg)) {
        $resultado = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
      var resposta = confirm('Seu CPF já consta em nossa base de Dados. Deseja atualizar?');
              if (resposta == true) {
              window.location = '".URL."trabalhe/home/".$cpf_key."#cadastro';
                                        }
               else {
               window.location = '".URL."trabalhe/home';
                                        }

                                </SCRIPT>";
    } else {
        $resultado = '';
    }
} else {
    $resultado = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
                                        alert('CPF inválido, favor verificar os dados digitados.');
                                        window.location = '".URL."trabalhe/home#cadastro';
                                   </SCRIPT>";
}
$retorno = $resultado;
                                        }

                                </SCRIPT>";
                    }
                    else {
                        $resultado = '';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $resultado = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
                                        alert('CPF inválido, favor verificar os dados digitados.');
                                        window.location = '" . URL . "trabalhe/home#cadastro';
                                   </SCRIPT>";
                }
                $retorno = $resultado;
```

Comment: _"não funciona em celulares"_ - em nenhum? android, ios?

Comment: Nenhum, testei em ambos.

Comment: Funciona bem para mim en IOS 10, iPhone 5 -> https://jsfiddle.net/wgchba2v/

Comment: :( testei no safari, google chrome, uc browser. Nenhum apresenta a mensagem.

Comment: O meu jsFiddle não funciona ou o teu código?

Comment: Funciona sim...

Comment: Podes criar um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema que tens para podermos testar?

Comment: Será que é o confirm? Troquei por alert funcionou.

Comment: Por favor então responda sua própria pergunta para fins de pesquisa e de resolução!

Comment: Removo o Post??

Comment: Não.  Coloque a solução aqui.